# Authorization issues

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to fetch the channels of an authenticated user, via oauth (rights to youtube data) and sign in via app engine. I keep getting an authorization issue. This was not happening as of yesterday. The details of the exception:

Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 OK
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}

looking at the Api Console status of Youtube Data Api, there are no issues. What could be causing this? I do have a youtube channel and not having one would have cause youtube sign up issue. Not sure what's going on. Is there any other dashboard I can look at to see if the youtube data api is experiencing any hiccups?

I use the following code to check that the user has a youtube channel upon login.

```
try { 
    YouTube.Channels.List channelRequest = youTubeProvider.get().channels().list("snippet");
    channelRequest.setMine(true); // return channels owned by the authenticated user
    ChannelListResponse channelListResponse = channelRequest.execute();
    List<Channel> channelList = channelListResponse.getItems();
    logger.info("YouTube channels fetched " + channelList.size());
    hasActiveYouTubeChannel = channelList.size() > 0;
  } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
  ...
  }
```

the exception is thrown and caught, e.statusCode == 401. Removing this check, I use my app and can upload and manipulate my channel in youtube just fine...

Comment: I use the following code to check that the user has a youtube channel upon login.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds wierd but im sure isn't a big deal, first of all i would double check the given password and username.. sounds stupid but could give a headache.also, if you try to login 3 times with wrong pass, you have to wait some time before log in again, and you would get an "authError" by this time.

after that i would check if you use an updated token, since if it expired you get "authError" also. to know if you using a valid token use this address:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={access_token}

replace the {access_token} with you token.

keep me updated if that help.